# Get Clipboard from Real iOS Device

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, appium-ios

I can not get the clipboard for Real iOS Device .. all the results are empty ..

> driver.getClipboard(ClipboardContentType.URL);
>   driver.getClipboard(ClipboardContentType.IMAGE);
>   driver.getClipboard(ClipboardContentType.PLAINTEXT);
>   driver.getClipboardText());
>   driver.getClipboardImage());

Although I can Set the Clipboard Successfully.. using the below method .

> driver.setClipboardText("Text");

is there a way to fix it , or is there a command in terminal that can get the clipboard ?

> OS: MacOS Mojave. Appium: 1.9 iPhone X (12.2).

Answer (score 0):

[Appium getClipboardText issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10290)

Appium does not provide any primitives for copying clipboard context on real device. Instead you can paste the text in any text field. Am using the following for my application.

```
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(iDriver);
//For pasting content
 ta.press(PointOption.point(x,y))
.waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
.perform();
By byPaste = By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeMenuItem[@name='Paste']");
iDriver.findElement(byPaste).click();
//Get the text in the text field            
element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay ,is there a way to support images like this?